# How to Autoplay youtube Video in IOS SDK 6?

Tags: video, youtube, ios6

Can any one Help me for starting/autoplay youtube video in IOS SDK 6?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google all video playback on the IOS must be user initiated. The following excerpt is from the YouTube API documentation:

"Warning: To prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at the user’s expense, embedded media cannot be played automatically in Safari on iOS — the user always initiates playback."

From the bottom of this page:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Apple will also deny submissions for apps that do not follow this rule, for obvious reasons.